# prints in an another window in cmd and close quickley

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a Perl script from command prompt.
The script contains one line:

```
     print "Hello World!\n"
```

I type in the cmd: `Perl hello.pl`
The line is printed in a new window and quickly is closed.

It's all happening in the cmd! Does anyone had this kind of problem?

I know Perl is working because I tried to run a script that creates an excel file and it worked.
The only problem is, that it doesn't print in the same window as it is supposed to do, but opens a new window, prints there and closes it. (I tried to do a while loop in the end and it didn't help).

Comment: Which operating system? If Windows, which Perl distribution?

Comment: ActivePerl-5.8.6.811-MSWin32-x86-122208

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this.

In windows there is an option called "Open command prompt as Administrator". A new window does not open up in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The cmd window closes as soon as the command that it runs has exited. You can either

- … start a cmd.exe of your own, and launch your script via

  ```
  > perl C:\path\to\script.pl
  ```

  instead of double-clicking the perl file (or whatever you are doing to start it). This should not start a new window.
- … or you could have the script wait until you have read the message. Just wait for user input of some sort before exiting, e.g. like

  ```
  <>;  # read and discard a line to exit
  ```

  at the bottom of your script.

  You can also use the `pause` program for this, which you can execute like `system('pause')`.